# How to get a table of labels in the .tex and their corresponding numbers in the .pdf?

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, ref

For doing corrections on my .tex files, it would be helpful to create a file with a table containing all the labels in one column and their corresponding equation, picture or theorem in the pdf. It would be even better if it could also give the page number.

Something like:

```
|     label in .tex      |      in the PDF       | page |
|------------------------|-----------------------|------|
| very_important_result  |      Theorem 5.32     | 107  |
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The labels and their page numbers are written out to the `.aux` file(s) during compilation with the command `\newlabel`.  This isn't in the convenient form you would like, but the syntax is uniform and should be able to be manipulated easily.

Comment: I found it now. It is not in the main .aux, but in it is the .aux of the corresponding file (I am using many files for my current work). This definitely helps, even though it isn't perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help.  That's why I said "file(s)".  I guess I could have been more specific, namely that if a project is composed of multiple files that are `\include`d, each such file will have its own `.aux` file.  (It's always useful to know where to find things, and it's not always obvious where to look.)

Comment: My bad, I didn't read the "(s)" the first time I read your comment.